# Textures doesn't show black color when used with "add shader"

Tags: materials, uv, image, color

I was modelling a fridge and there is a LCD display beneath metal cover. So i just wanted to add texture over the cover. but when i do that, black colored parts of the texture didn't appear.

result:
[image: result]

The Texture:
[image: The Texture]

My nodes:
[image: my nodes]

the "Add Shader" node's first plug is for the screen texture, second plug is for brushed metal sufrace.

I also thought that if i can select the white and black color separately, i can combine them later on but there is no such procedure in vanilla blender as far as i saw on the internet.

well i ended up using the black areas also glowing, since i can't do it with one texture and poking around with nodes, i am gonna slice that face into pieces and change unwrapping

[image]

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now.  Black on an emission map doesn't mean emit black, it means emit nothing

Comment: The black color should probably come from a black piece of glass planted under the panel, and the color emits from that through the top layer

Comment: It would be a solution but most likely a work-around. The actual problem isn't sloved.

Answer (score 0):

Using image's alpha instead of color, makes possible to see black areas. But it makes the black areas also glowing, which is not that important to me anymore